# Can't install .exe files

Tags: 18.04, wine

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4

I want to use following applications on my laptop

1. RadiAnt DICOM Viewer
2. Windows movie maker

Kindly tell me which version of wine should i install and how to do it?

Comment: BTW, which versions of those software do you have?

Comment: Also, have you checked whether those applications are marked as working OK under Wine?

Comment: I plan to download latest versions of these softwares

Comment: i dont know how to check whether an application is marked as working OK under wine

Comment: @Ajay usually check via WineHQ (e.g. the links in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Generally I would use the version of Wine that comes with Ubuntu.

1. RadiAnt DICOM Viewer should work with pretty much any version of wine -- [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=16624)
2. Windows movie maker is unlikely to work well with any version of Wine -- [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6183)

Comment: please tell me how to install, i tried installing via software centre (version 3.0) but it wont open .exe files

Comment: I do it by finding the `.exe` in a terminal and running `wine /path/to/EXAMPLE.exe`. You may also be able to just double click the `.exe` file in your filemanager.

Comment: thanks gmatht! finally managed to install wine 5.0 and using radiant dicom viewer now!